# DHCP Internal Lan Wrong Leases

Tags: dhcp

I have a Wireless Interface in bridge mode.

I setup a DHCP Server listening on bridge-local interface.

Moreover, I have an ethernet1 with `192.168.1.202.`
`10.1.0.0/24` on `bridge-local` itnerface.

The DHCP Server pool is `10.1.0.2.`

For some reason the wireless clientes (but also the wired ones) get address from 192.168.1.1 and not from 10.1.0.1.
Therefore, they get wrong addresses (in 192 pool and not 10.1.0.x pool)
why?
More
details

```
[admin@MikroTik] /ip dhcp-server> print
 #   NAME                    INTERFACE                    RELAY           ADDRESS-POOL                    LEASE-TIME ADD-ARP
 0   default                 bridge-local                                 pool2                           10m       
 1 I server-local            inside                                       pool2                           10m   

  [admin@MikroTik] /ip address> print
Flags: X - disabled, I - invalid, D - dynamic 
 #   ADDRESS            NETWORK         INTERFACE                                                                           
 0   ;;; default configuration
     192.168.88.1/24    192.168.88.0    bridge-local                                                                        
 1   10.1.0.1/24        10.1.0.0        bridge-local                                                                        
 2 X 10.1.0.22/24       10.1.0.0        Uffici                                                                              
 3   192.168.1.202/24   192.168.1.0     outisde (to )isp router  



 [admin@MikroTik] /interface> print
Flags: D - dynamic, X - disabled, R - running, S - slave 
 #     NAME                                TYPE       ACTUAL-MTU L2MTU  MAX-L2MTU MAC-ADDRESS      
 0     dmz                                 ether            1500  1598       4074 00:0C:42:8D:56:64
 1   S ether2                              ether            1500  1598       4074 00:0C:42:8D:56:61
 2   S ether4                              ether            1500  1598       4074 00:0C:42:8D:56:63
 3   S ether6-master-local                 ether            1500  1598       2028 00:0C:42:8D:56:65
 4   S ether7-slave-local                  ether            1500  1598       2028 00:0C:42:8D:56:66
 5   S ether8-slave-local                  ether            1500  1598       2028 00:0C:42:8D:56:67
 6   S ether9-slave-local                  ether            1500  1598       2028 00:0C:42:8D:56:68
 7   S ether10-slave-local                 ether            1500  1598       2028 00:0C:42:8D:56:69
 8  RS inside                              ether            1500  1598       4074 00:0C:42:8D:56:62
 9  R  outisde (to )isp router             ether            1500  1598       4074 00:0C:42:8D:56:60
10   S sfp1                                ether            1500  1598       4074 00:0C:42:8D:56:5F
11  RS Uffici                              wlan             1500  2290            00:0C:42:8D:56:6A
12  R  bridge-local                        bridge           1500  1598            00:0C:42:8D:56:61
```

Comment: Do you have the wired and wireless networks bridged? They will get the same address range from a DHCP server. What is your router model, and do you have a DHCP server configured on it?

Comment: You should bridge networks with the same IP address range, but not networks with different IP address ranges Route between different networks, bridge on the same network. A DHCP request is a broadcast on the network, and a DHCP server on a broadcast domain is only going to assign IP addresses from one network to that network since it can't tell which host should get which addresses. If the router has a DHCP server enabled, it could answer before a stand-alone DHCP server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was as simple as stupid.
Another guy carelessly put a DHCP server in another room (without my consensus)!

Comment: Happens all the time ;)

Comment: Good idea to use /ip dhcp-server alert

/ip dhcp-server alert add disabled=no interface=bridge-local

Comment: You should accept your answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer.

Answer (score -1):

### [DHCP Snooping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DHCP_snooping)

In computer networking, DHCP snooping is a series of techniques applied to improve the security of a DHCP infrastructure.

When DHCP servers are allocating IP addresses to the clients on the LAN, DHCP snooping can be configured on LAN switches to allow only clients with specific IP and MAC addresses to have access to the network.

DHCP snooping can ensure IP integrity on a Layer 2 switched domain. It works with information from a DHCP server to:

Track the physical location of hosts.
Ensure that hosts only use the IP addresses assigned to them.
Ensure that only authorized DHCP servers are accessible.
With DHCP snooping, the information about IP addresses and corresponding MAC addresses is stored in a database on the network switch. Packets from clients that do not match the stored information will be dropped.

The DHCP snooping database sometimes is used for other security features such as IP source guard and dynamic ARP inspection, which makes it a central component of LAN access security.

DHCP snooping can also prevent attackers from adding their own DHCP servers to the network, causing malfunction of the network and adding further unauthorized components.